# No console after installing new kernel (from ELRepo)

Tags: linux, boot, centos, kernel

I got a new Dell R530 server recently and have installed Centos 7.5 (1804) on it (tried 17.04 as well!). I installed new kernel from elrepo on the system. The issue I am encountering is that if I boot from new kernel I would not get console (I can still SSH but no console on the machine), but if I boot from the default kernel (the kernel that centos comes with), things work! I have updated kernel on other R530 machines we got in the past without any issues! 
Any idea what might cause this and if there is a fix for it?

Comment: Ask centos team: https://bugs.centos.org/main_page.php

Comment: Thanks. I did ask them. They just advise to use the supported kernels (no third party kernel). So basically they did not answer my question.